# How many lines can we write in a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I created a visualforce page, and wrote 175,342 lines of code in it. The total view state is 38 kb. I need to add another 1,000 lines of code, at least, to the page. When I try to do this, I get the error "max length=1048".

How can I resolve this?

Comment: That is an absolutely insane amount of markup.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't copy by mistake an entire [Harry Potter Book Series](https://wordcounter.net/blog/2015/11/23/10922_how-many-words-harry-potter.html) content in there?

Answer (score 5):

Here what I can see is there are so many lines of code present in your Visualforce page in order to handle complex functionality.

You can use templating feature of visualforce , where you can add similar block of code inside a Visualforce component and make size of your page small.

You can read more about this here.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_templates_intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

Depends on size of VF page. maximum size of visualForce page 135 KB. I think you have exceeded 135 KB . You can also check the page size from view state of your page.

Go to Setup > My Personal Information > Personal Information > Check Development Mode > Check Show View State in Development Mode.

Refer to below links.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000976hIAA

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_vf.htm

Comment: OP said: "view state is 38kb".